# How to set an image responsive within a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[image]

I have this image of a smiling house within a div [**here**](http://www.egggeo.com/parallax/) and i tried making it responsive using:

> *img-responsive(Bootstrap class)
>
> *background-size:cover;
>   background-size:contain;
>   background-size:auto;

Gave these separately.
All have failed....Anyone got any better solution?

PS:The position of text and image shouldn't be changed.

**Found the solution: I removed the div and added just the image. It works fine now.**

Answer (score -1):

Your `background-size:auto;` overrides the previous settings.

Cover will stretch to fit the div, causing clipping. Contain will stretch to fit without clipping.

```
background-image: url(''); 
background-size: contain; 
background-position:center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: I tried background-size: contain; ,but after a particular width of the broswer.. the picture went too small..